# I'm getting 0 qty in depth stream on binance

Tags: rust, postman, binance, binance-api-client

When connected to `wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/ethusdt@depth` in place of a quantity i sometimes (in fact quite often) get 0 like in example message:

```
{
    "e": "depthUpdate",
    "E": 1623439441427,
    "s": "ETHUSDT",
    "U": 8550164870,
    "u": 8550165574,
    "b": [
        [
            "2406.49000000",
            "0.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.48000000",
            "0.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.35000000",
            "0.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.25000000",
            "0.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.23000000",
            "0.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.21000000",
            "0.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.20000000",
            "0.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.19000000",
            "0.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.17000000",
            "0.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.16000000",
            "0.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.15000000",
            "0.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.14000000",
            "0.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.01000000",
            "0.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2405.99000000",
            "0.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2405.97000000",
            "0.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2405.96000000",
            "0.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2405.95000000",
            "0.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2405.94000000",
            "0.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2405.93000000",
            "0.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2405.86000000",
            "0.00000000"
        ],
        
    ],
    "a": [
        [
            "2405.59000000",
            "0.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2405.60000000",
            "0.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2405.61000000",
            "0.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2405.64000000",
            "0.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2405.65000000",
            "0.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2405.66000000",
            "0.95380000"
        ],
        [
            "2405.67000000",
            "8.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2405.83000000",
            "0.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.10000000",
            "0.98850000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.11000000",
            "3.31912000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.12000000",
            "3.28392000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.13000000",
            "0.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.16000000",
            "0.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.17000000",
            "0.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.18000000",
            "0.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.19000000",
            "0.32100000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.20000000",
            "0.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.21000000",
            "0.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.22000000",
            "0.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.23000000",
            "0.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.26000000",
            "1.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.29000000",
            "3.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.30000000",
            "0.75917000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.31000000",
            "0.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.36000000",
            "0.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.37000000",
            "0.54000000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.46000000",
            "7.81255000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.47000000",
            "10.38000000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.48000000",
            "3.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.49000000",
            "1.50103000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.50000000",
            "0.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.51000000",
            "1.48621000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.62000000",
            "0.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.63000000",
            "9.40536000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.64000000",
            "17.91499000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.70000000",
            "2.76583000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.78000000",
            "0.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.79000000",
            "0.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.80000000",
            "0.06000000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.81000000",
            "0.00000000"
        ],
        [
            "2406.83000000",
            "0.00000000"
        ],
    ]
}
```

Here the second number in each pair represents Bid or Ask quantity.
I get the same exact behavior in Postman and using rust client library on other coin pairs as well.
Is it intentional or some kind of a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal. I don't know why binance does not fix this, but as API doc say you should ignore it.

[How to manage a local order book correctly](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#how-to-manage-a-local-order-book-correctly)

> If the quantity is 0, remove the price level.